# how to configure timeouts for MongoDB compass?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, connection-string, configure

I am trying to find out how to configure timeouts for MonogDB compass.

I tried to google, but couldn't get any answers

Answer (score 0):

For MongoDB Compass specifically ...

When you first open and pick your connection:

- Toggle open the `Advanced Connection Options`
- Select the `Advanced` Tab
- At the bottom there is a dropdown with extra connection options, including timeouts

There you can configure it and it'll add it to your connection string, as documented here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#mongodb-urioption-urioption.connectTimeoutMS

**MongoDB Compass**

[image]